# "Reflection" and incompatible pointer types in C

Tags: c

I'm following a pseudocode snippet in a CompSci paper and trying to implement it in C. In this paper, I have two `structs`, say `A` and `B`. One of them goes something like this:

```
struct A {
  B* next;
  int data;
}
```

while `B` looks like

```
struct B {
  A* next;
}
```

Now, for a given instantiation `a` of `A` and `b` of `B`, at some point the algorithm tells me to do two things:

- if `a` is not `B`, then *do stuff*,
- a = b

Now, I cannot do reflection in C, and I will obviously get incompatible pointer types for the second requirement. I thought about having a `union` in the `A` struct, and perhaps that would help, but I'd like to ask you guys if there's a good design I'm missing.

Comment: Are you certain it isn't a.next = b ?

Comment: Not sure I understand this. `a` should *never* be `b` because they are of different types... If at some point `A* a == (A*)b` then dereferencing `a` would be UB.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I am. It's somehow "swapping" the objects.

Comment: @netcoder: you may be right for the second point (there are no types in the pseudocode, so I may have got that wrong, will check again). I'm still left with the first problem though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but he could create a structure that works as a wrapper, wrapping a structure of type A or B with a void pointer, with another additional field of type char representing the type.Would this break the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: maybe a link to the paper could clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are venturing into dangerous territory here.  It appears that you are trying to implement polymorphism in a language which has no built in support for it.

There are several schemes you could use which allow you to have an `struct A*` actually point to memory containing a `struct B`.  A union is probably the least dangerous.  But as you point out, there is no reflection.  Any pointer only knows that it points to a block of memory, and one way to interpret that block if it is dereferenced.  `void` pointers don't even know that last part.   The only way to do type identification is to insert a value identifying the type somewhere in the structure.

Something like this:

```
struct generic {
   enum {ATYPE,BTYPE} type;
   union {
      struct A a;
      struct B b;
    };
};


function process(struct generic* a, struct generic* b)
{
   if (a.type != BTYPE)
   { //do stuff 
   }
   else 
   { 
      *a = *b;
   }
}
```

-edit-
on the other hand, if the content of the structures is as simple as you describe, you could 
simply add an `isB` member to `struct a`, and only use one type.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this is supposed to do, but here is what you do to make it compile:

```
struct a a;
struct b b;

typedef struct a
{
  struct b* next;
  int data;
} A;

typedef struct b
{
  A* next;
} B;

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, if your struct's are defined in the correct way, then your algorithm should be described that way:

- if (a != b->next) then do stuff
- a=b->next;

But in this case, the assignment of a=b->next makes only sense if a!=b->next, so it should be moved into the "do stuff"-thing

To make it compilable, you just can add a forward-decl to B in front of the A-definition:

```
struct B;
struct A {
  B* next;
  int data;
};
struct B {
  A* next;
};
int main () {
  A *a=...;
  B *b=...;
  if (a!=b->next) {
    //do stuff
  }
  a = b->next;
}
```